# Fix syntax checking in SQL Server when using synonyms

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Whether in a script window or in a stored procedure, is there any way to get SQL Server Management Studio to follow the current target a synonym points to so that syntax checking works? I'm writing SQL statements that reference a synonym that may, at different times, point to a table in one or another instance (dev, test, etc.) of the same database. It would be really nice if I didn't have red squiggles under all of the column names belonging to the underlying table when I know they're correct! Is there any way to get SSMS to figure out that they're correct?

Comment: Intellisense doesn't connect to linked hosts to obtain the objects and column names. This, presumably, is by design, as it could be horrendously slow.

Comment: I think what you are asking for may exist in Redgate tools as one of the options for their SQL Prompt.  Thought I may not be understanding your question fully.